# Problem with connecting my PI Samb Server to windows

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, windows, samba

Guides I used to create this:

- [Build a Raspberry Pi NAS](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/build-a-raspberry-pi-nas)
- [How to Turn a Raspberry Pi Into a NAS for Whole-Home File Sharing](https://uk.pcmag.com/news/124258/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-nas-for-whole-home-file-sharing)

So currently I created a Samba server with x2 external HDDs in raid 1. I believe virtual partitions are set up correctly and are working.

I was getting `You can’t access this shared folder because your organization’s security policies block unauthenticated guest access`, so I changed my windows 10 unauthenticated guest access in the user group policy settings which resulted in me just getting.

```
The error: 0x8007035, the network path was not found. 
I am putting in the correct path of \ \ (RASPBERRY PI IP ADDRESS) \ Directory but I keep getting the error.
```

I currently have no idea what I am doing wrong so any help would be appreciated, I suspect there is something wrong with my config file. Thank you for your help in advance.

below is my Samb config file ( is it the default file with the below added onto the bottom):

```
[mnt]
path = /mnt
writeable = yes
create mask = 0775
directory mask = 0775
public=no
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you created a user for Samba (with password) and are you using that to authenticate? The *public=no* will stop access without the authentication.

Are you 100% sure you have the correct IP address?

You could try adding

*server min protocol = SMB2*

to the global section of your config file

Also check the rights on the mount point - its possible they are root only.